# How to prevent URL parameters escaping in Paw 3

Tags: paw-app

Paw 3 automatically escapes URL parameters, so `type=x+y` becomes `type=x%2By`. This causes server to mis-interpret parameter and returns wrong values. Is it possible to prevent this URL escape taking place?

Comment: It's not possible in the current (early) versions of Paw 3. We're working on a fix that will let some params be encoded and some others optionally not, to give more flexibility to all users. We should be able to push a fix soon.

Comment: Cool, thanks, looking forward!

Comment: Any updates to this?